# Adding unique titles to subplots within a for-loop in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, matplotlib, subplot

I've checked other answers on SO that haven't seemed to help me solve this issue. I have created subplots from a column in a `pandas` `df`. I wish for each `subplot`to have a unique date at the end of each title which I had tried to do in a loop. What happens is that a title only appears on the last graph and no others. Why is this?

```
area2011 = df_2011.groupby(['Area Id']).size()
area2012 = df_2012.groupby(['Area Id']).size()
area2013 = df_2013.groupby(['Area Id']).size()
area2014 = df_2014.groupby(['Area Id']).size()
area2015 = df_2015.groupby(['Area Id']).size()
area2016 = df_2016.groupby(['Area Id']).size()
area_list = [area2011, area2012, area2013, area2014, area2015, area2016]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3)
for i in range(2011, 2017):
    for d, ax in zip(area_list, axes.ravel()):
        plt.title(f'Area Id crimes in {i}')
        d.plot.bar(ax=ax, figsize=(15, 7))
        plt.tight_layout()
```

From the first to the last `subplot`I want to produce:

```
"Area Id crimes in 2011"
   .
   .
   .
"Area Id crimes in 2016"
```

Comment: `ax.set_title()`?

Comment: try `ax.title.set_text(f'Area Id crimes in {i}')`

Comment: @QuangHoang Both solutions just print on all subplots "Area Id crimes in 2016". It doesn't loop in the range

Comment: @MohamedThasinah

Comment: Why the double `for` loop: `for i in range(2011, 2017):
    for d, ax in zip(area_list, axes.ravel()):`?

Comment: @QuangHoang no reason in particular apart from the range. Shall I replace this with `count = 2011` then `count+=1` in the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's quicker to post an answer. So here it goes:

```
for i in range(2011, 2017):
    for d, ax in zip(area_list, axes.ravel()):
        plt.title(f'Area Id crimes in {i}')
        d.plot.bar(ax=ax, figsize=(15, 7))
        plt.tight_layout()
```

The outer `for` loops, at last run (`i=2016`), will set everything to `f'Area Id crimes in {i}'` which is `'Area Id crimes in 2016'`.

```
for d, i in zip(area_list, range(6)):
    ax = axes.ravel()[i];
    ax.set_title(f'Area Id crimes in {i+2011}')
    d.plot.bar(ax=ax, figsize=(15, 7))
    plt.tight_layout()
```